# UICollectionView with dynamic Section and Row iOS Swift 3.

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have collectionView in iOS Swift 3. In which 5 section and 5 row currently. this will be dynamic section and row. In each row and section i have textfield . My question is how to i detect textfield in textfield action  func textFieldDidChange(textfieldChange: UITextField){}. i need to know textfield tag with section and row position. so that i can store textfield value into single Array. As i detect textfield tag of each section from 0 to 4 index. but textfield tag change in each section and textfield tag initialise 0 to 4 in each section. Here my textfield  action function

```
func textFieldDidChange(textfieldChange: UITextField){
      }
```

Comment: add target to textfield in collectiveview cell. give it tag and you will be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Set button tag like this in `cellForRow`

```
let tag = indexPath.section*100 + indexPath.row
btnABC.tag = tag
```

Get row and section of the particular button on button action

```
let tag = sender.tag // make sure sender is button type.
let Row = tag % 100
let Section = (tag - Row)/100
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the section and Row value of the CollectionView's Item in which your textfield is, By using below code in you textfield's delegate method :

```
let item:UICollectionViewCell = textField.superview?.superview as! UICollectionViewCell

 let indexPath = collection_view.indexPath(for: item)

 print(" Section :\(indexPath?.section)")
 print(" Row :\(indexPath?.row)")
 print(" Item :\(indexPath?.item)")
```

Comment: Apparently row ==item in UICollection, so this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

```
let collectionIndexPath = textfield.superview?.superview as! UICollectionViewCell
print(collectionIndexPath.row)
print(collectionIndexPath.section)
```